# Non-Interactive commands in Solaris non global zones

Tags: solaris

I want to run multiple commands on each non global zone without login. This is possible by using the Non-Interactive Mode but the question is how can we create a script for each command on every non global zone.

Below is an example. This works manually but I'm unable to create a script.

```
zlogin my-zone1 ps -ef | grep -i oracle  

zlogin my-zone2 ps -ef | grep -i oracle  

zlogin my-zone3 ps -ef | grep -i oracle  

tcsh>zoneadm list -civ  
  ID NAME             STATUS     PATH                           BRAND    IP  
   0 global           running    /                              native   shared  
   1 myZone1          running    /export/zones/myZone1          native   shared  
   2 myZone2          running    /export/zones/myZone2          native   shared  
   3 myZone3          installed  /export/zones/myZone2          native   shared
```

If a zone in in the installed state, how the output will come ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way:

```
for zone in $(zoneadm list -civ | nawk '$2 != "global" && $3 == "running" {print $2}'); do
    echo ==== $zone ====
    zlogin $zone ps -ef | grep -i oracle
done
```

Note that if the zone isn't in a running state, there is no point trying to run `ps` in it.

Depending on what you are precisely looking to, better solutions based on `pgrep` and `ps` might be simpler.

Edit:

If you want non running zones to be displayed:

```
zoneadm list -civ | nawk '$2 !~ "(global|NAME)" {print $2 " " $3}') | while read name status
do
    echo ==== $name ====
    case "$status" in
    (running) zlogin $zone ps -ef | grep -i oracle ;;
    (*) echo $status ;;
    esac
done
```

Comment: This is the exact thing which i wanted but the oly thing is if the zone are in installed state then how could it gets print

Comment: If the zone is in the installed state, i.e. not running, what do you expect to be printed ?

Comment: my-zone2 installed  my-zone3 installed

Comment: What is the script displaying ? Any error message ? (please post the output in you question, not as a comment, if longer than one line.)